# Using the determinant to detect invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, determinant

A homework problem of mine asks me to use the determinant to see if the matrix is invertible. After using cofactor expansion, I got *-48* as the determinant, and because -48 =/= 0, this appears to be invertible. However, an explanation for this problem on another website states that it is not invertible because the determinant is 0. What did I do wrong here?[image]

Edit: Below is the written work I have for this problem.[image]

Comment: You'll probably have to show us your working for the determinant. Otherwise the best we can say is "the determinant is indeed 0".

Comment: Oop. Well. You're right. I'll go ahead and add my work.

Comment: Why is the coefficient of the second term "$-(6(-1)^3)$"? Where did the $-$ and $(-1)^3$ come from? It is the sign of this term caused the mistake.

Comment: Either leave the sign in the $(-1)^{i + j}$, or remove the $(-1)^{i + j}$ and leave the sign in the $\pm 6$. You seem to have done both.

Comment: You can also see that (the first row + the second row = the third row), so by elementary operations, you can get a row full of zeros, hence the determinant is zero.